# Reverse socks5 using SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, ssh-tunneling, socks

Setup:

- Server is a virtual machine
- Server have a local ip adress
- Server is restricted so that it can't reach the internet (not sure how)
- Client machine have access to both server via SSH
- Client have unrestricted access to the internet
- I have root on both server and client (running Arch Linux on client and Gentoo on server)
- Server can't access the client

All of this is probably due to heavily locked down firewalls.

Problem: I need to be able to fetch packages and source code from the internet.

Is it possible to set up the client so that it can proxy internet bound traffic for the server during updates?

Comment: If you have root access to both, you might be able to use the client as a NAT gateway for the server. To be honest, I have to ask why the server does not have internet access? Are you trying to get around a company policy?

Comment: @M_dk Yeah, I also wonder why server don't have internet access. But I think that it's default for any new server instance. I can't use client as NAT because the same firewall that prevents server from accessing the internet, is preventing any outbound connections apart from a couple of specific internal servers that the service is dependent upon.

Answer (score 2):

A possibility could be to download whatever you need from your client and then send those files by `scp` to your server if it accept `scp`.

```
scp file_to_send user@server_ip:/location_of_the_file
```

I don't know if what your asking is possible as your server has no acces to the client.

Comment: Yes, that's how I set up my environment on the server now. However my first impulse were to try and proxy any traffic through the work station.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier if you set the network mode to `NAT`.

But since `pacman` can be configured to use sock5 proxy, you might start a socks5 client with ssh (on port 9090 in this example)

`ssh -f -N dummy@host -D 9090`

Then you configure your pacman mirrors (which is /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist). You must use IP addresses if DNS request were also "blocked":

`Server = http://149.20.4.71/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch`

And let pacman use curl with a socks5 proxy. Append this to the `[options]` section of /etc/pacman.conf,

`XferCommand = /usr/bin/curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:9090 -C - -f %u > %o`

Now you may run `pacman -Syu` to start a upgrade ;-P

Comment: Actually the problem is that the server can't access the internet. The workstation has internet access fine. Therefore my question is whether I can proxy traffic from server through the workstation where the workstation is the initiator of the SSH-session.